# Cant connect to a external server (api) in socket io

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

Im trying to connect to a only api but is not working, is giving me a error of:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.sports/socket.io/?api_key=aredasdasdadds&EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LsYSPsv. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 596.
```

The strange thing is in the error showing a different api url.

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Web socket</h1>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


    // Create SocketIO instance, connect

    var socket = new io('https://api.sports.com/soccer-/eu/en/matches/summary.json?api_key=aredasdasdadds');
    socket.connect();

    // Add a connect listener
    socket.on('connect',function() {
        console.log('Client has connected to the server!');
    });
    // Add a connect listener
    socket.on('message',function(data) {
        console.log('Received a message from the server!',data);
    });


    // Sends a message to the server via sockets
    function sendMessageToServer(message) {
        socket.send(message);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That URL doesn't look like it's a Socket.IO endpoint. Are you trying to _retrieve_ that URL? If so, use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Answer (score 0):

What is your server?

First, ou have to check that the version of socket.io is the same on the client and on the server (I see that on client is 2.0.3).

Secondly, you only need use the domain of your web like this:

```
  var socket = io.connect('ws://https://api.sports.com:8443/', {transports: ['websocket']});
```

And set the port to listen, usually is 8443 for https.

Regards!